# Is it possibel extract thumbnails and save them on website using youtube video. (by front-end users)

Tags: video, printing, youtube, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I read blog about print youtube video on "http://www.labnol.org/internet/print-youtube-video/28217/".

I have a self-hosted video site.

But video hosting makes too many traffic.

So I decideed another plan for site.

It's to generate thumbnails of external video. Is it possible?

I found making thumbnails using ffmpeg, but there are a lot of videos in external platform(Like Youtube, Vimeo, etc)

After I saw Amit Agarwal's blog("print youtube video"), I was very impressed.

Anyway if it is impossible, I should find another way.

Thanks-

Comment: i would firstly look at youtubes terms and conditions and see if this is actually allowed before you go ahead and implement this

Answer (score 0):

Why dont make a simple screenshot? on OS X with cmd+shift+4 / on Windows use the Snipping tool...

Comment: Because if it is not illegal(youtube terms and conditions), it should be making another content using many sources(video). ex) more visual video reviews, more detail guide.